# Rails precompile multiple javascript_includes_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags, include

I'm actually building a new app under Rails 4. 
I used to put my `javascript_includes_tag` at the bottom of my layout. But for an unknown reason, it creates a bug when trying to use `confirm:` on delete link.
So I put back this line at the top :

```
!!!
%html{ :lang => 'en' }
  %head
    = stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
    = javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
```

So far so good, the bug is now gone. Anyway, since my app is gonna use a lot of Javascript, I still need to load those third part library at the bottom. So, what I did is to only let the Rails library at the top :

```
// application.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
```

Then I tried to create another js file named `third-part` and try to do the same as `application` but including my third part libraries. Unfortunately, it does not work.

```
// third-part.js
//= require bootstrap
//= require app
//= require app.plugin
```

How can I add another `javascript_includes_tag` at the bottom the same way I did for application? Here I mean that on production it will also compress those files.

Thanks a lot for your help

EDIT :
It's actually loading my files well on DEVELOPMENT, but not on my production.
On production I just got `<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/javascripts/third-part.js"></script>` and I can't access the file

I've tried :

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( third-part.js )
```

and

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

but it still not working

EDIT 2 :
I made a test of precompliling on production mode from my local machine. It did work. It might be a problem with my server.

EDIT 3 :
Just earse my application from server and clone a new one from my Github but it's still not working. Don't know why :(

Comment: Can you post the content of third-part here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your config/environments/production.rb add this line to precompile the external assets

```
config.assets.precompile += ["third-part.js"]
```

and don't forget to mention env=production while precompiling assets on production.

Comment: Sorry, I just edit my post. It's actually loading files only in development. On production I just got `<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/javascripts/third-part.js"></script>` and I can't access the file

Comment: Have you included like this on your page?  = javascript_include_tag "third-part", "data-turbolinks-track" => true

Comment: Yeah, I did it exactly like that. Is that the cause of the problem?

Comment: If it is working on your local machine in production env. Then there could be some permissions issue on your production server.

Comment: Well, the end of the end is definitely not a good time for me to work. I stupidly forgot to push my modifications online :(